# SwiftUI: Decide which content the keyboard overlaps

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikeyboard

I'm trying to find a way to mark which content is overlapped by the keyboard that pops up when a `TextField` is focused.

Consider the minimal example below:

```
VStack {
            
    TextField(text: $text) {}
            
    Spacer()
            
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

I'm looking for a custom modifier that I could apply to the `Circle`. This would dictate whether the keyboard should push the `Circle` up above the keyboard, as is default, or if the keyboard should overlap the `Circle` (I'm not sure how to get the keyboard to simply overlap a view, either).

So far I've found primarily Objective-C solutions... Are there any SwiftUI ways to go about this? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your goal then you don't need custom modifier - there is standard modifier, which you can either add or remove, or use with some condition.

```
VStack {
    TextField(text: $text) {}
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

    VStack {
        Spacer()

        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)    // << here !!
    //.ignoresSafeArea(yourFlag ? .keyboard : .container, edges: .bottom) // << alternate
}
```